# Word Addin font selection bar

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

Is it possible to add a bar like the one below to a custom word addin with a set of predefined fonts?

[image: Font Bar]

If so what is the property called that represents one of these bars and if possible is there any information online that explains how to create one of these?

Comment: What you have highlighted is the STYLES tab of the RIbbon - it's not just fonts, it's the way the style definition looks. And no, this kind of control is not exposed to third-party developers. Possibly, you could construct something like this in a _Custom Task Pane_, using WinForms or WPF controls and graphics of the individual fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change or re-use that control, but you can control the styles that are listed, and the attributes of each style. It sounds like that's what you want. It doesn't even have to be in an Add-In, you can do it for any document or template.

[image: Manage styles]

You can also manage them in code, though to a slightly lesser degree I believe.